# Qu'elle tienne "informé" les usagers ou "informés" ?

Tags: accord

Bonjour,
J'ai un doute sur l'accord en genre et en nombre lorsque le mot concerné est placé avant le sujet ?

Faut-il écrire:

> "qu'elle tienne informé les usagers des plans de transports"

ou

> "qu'elle tienne informés les usagers des plans de transports"

Merci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Informés" est ici un attribut du complément d'objet, il s'accorde donc avec le complément d'objet dont il est l'attribut (sa position par rapport au sujet n'a pas d'importance). Ce complément d'objet est ici "usagers", donc la forme correcte est:

> Qu'elle tienne informés les usagers des plans de transport.

Comment: Merci beaucoup Greg ;)